# SQL query breakdown the sales by each hour

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query as below which will return each Remote server sales for today
Result as per below

```
datebooking NameOfDay   ORC CWP TC  TotalBooking    EmailSent   EmailNotSent
20150524    Sunday      447 144 272  1441           1441           0
```

The datebooking actually i have it trim down to 8 numeric

My question is could I return each remote sales server breakdown by per hour? Imagine one day will be 24 lines of details instead of one line per day
That mean under booking date will we in this format 20150524 12am to 1am sales, 2am  to 3am so on and so forth? How should I accomplish this query based on my current query?

```
SELECT 
    Convert(char(8), OrderH_dtmInitiated, 112)as datebooking,
      Datename (weekday, OrderH_dtmInitiated) As NameOfDay,
       --count(distinct OrderH_strCinemaId)as Cinemasite,   
       SUM(case when OrderH_strCinemaId like '1101' then 1 else 0 end)as ORC,
       SUM(case when OrderH_strCinemaId like '1102' then 1 else 0 end)as CWP,
       SUM(case when OrderH_strCinemaId like '1104' then 1 else 0 end)as TC,
       count(distinct OrderH_intID)as TotalBooking,  
       SUM(case when OrderH_strEmailConfirmationSent like 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) as EmailSent,
       SUM(case when OrderH_strEmailConfirmationSent is NULL then 1 else 0 end) as EmailNotSent   

    FROM [VISTAIT].[dbo].[tblOrderHistory]
    WHERE OrderH_dtmInitiated >= (SELECT     DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE() )))
    GROUP BY Convert(char(8), OrderH_dtmInitiated, 112), Datename (weekday, OrderH_dtmInitiated )
    ORDER by Convert(char(8), OrderH_dtmInitiated, 112)
```

Comment: You can group by the date_diff(hour, base_date,transactions_date), if your transactions have date time timestamps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would just add the hour to the `select` and `group by`:

```
SELECT Convert(char(8), OrderH_dtmInitiated, 112) as datebooking,
       datename(hour, OrderH_dtmInitiated) as hourbooking,
       . . .
FROM . . .
GRUOP BY Convert(char(8), OrderH_dtmInitiated, 112),
         datename(hour, OrderH_dtmInitiated)
```

This assumes that `OrderH_dtmInitiated` actually has the time information.

And alternative method would be to use a date/time format that includes the hour, so it is easy to put into one field:

```
SELECT Convert(char(13), OrderH_dtmInitiated, 121) as datebooking,
       . . .
FROM . . .
GROUP BY Convert(char(13), OrderH_dtmInitiated, 121)
```

The format would then be "YYYY-MM-DD HH".

EDIT:

If you want am/pm for the hour, probably the easiest way is an explicit `case`:

```
SELECT Convert(char(8), OrderH_dtmInitiated, 112) as datebooking,
       (CASE WHEN datename(hour, OrderH_dtmInitiated) < '12'
             THEN datename(hour, OrderH_dtmInitiated) + ' AM'
             ELSE datename(hour, OrderH_dtmInitiated) + ' PM'
        END) as hourbooking,
       . . .
FROM . . .
GRUOP BY Convert(char(8), OrderH_dtmInitiated, 112),
         datename(hour, OrderH_dtmInitiated)
```

Note:  I wrote the logic using only `datename()` quite intentionally.  That way, the whole `case` statement doesn't need to be in the `group by` clause.

Comment: Correct, Gordon you are right! thanks, one more qns could I add in AM, PM? "YYYY-MM-DD HH am/pm"?

Comment: Thanks Gordon! Greatly appreciate